# Cant disable button if use "data-role="button" disabled"

Tags: html, button, kendo-mobile

I’m using Kendo Mobile and Jquery.
I have just tried to disable a button in all the ways I can think of but nothing is happening, it is still clickable. The below code should show this in a kendo project. It is particularly only happening if "`data-role="button"`" is in the line and is disabled when that’s not there.

Whats going on and how can I fix it?

```
<header data-role="header">
     <div data-role="navbar">
     <a data-role="backbutton" data-align="left">Back</a>
     <span data-role="view-title"></span>
     <a id="colourNextButton" href="#products-found-view" data-role="button" data-bind="click: setChosenColours" data-transition="slide:left" data-align="right" disabled >Next</a>
     </div>
</header>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it through javascript?

```
$('#colourNextButton').button( "disable" );
```

also i remember seeing somewhere that in general you should use disabled="disabled" instead of just writing disabled

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not supported, however disabling buttons and switches is planned for the next major release, due in about 2 months.